# How to add a library dependency in a dune project that manages the .opam file without an intermediate build error?

Tags: ocaml, opam, dune

dune will generate and update a project's `.opam` file when you run `dune build`, letting you just manage the project's dependencies in `dune-project`.

However, this seems to require an awkward step when adding a new dependency. The only sequence of events I can figure out seems to be:

1. Add new dependencies to `dune-project`'s `depends` stanza.
2. `dune build`: updates the `.opam` file with the new dependency, and fails with errors about the missing new dependencies.
3. `opam install . --deps-only`
4. `dune build`: succeeds.

Is this the intended flow? The step in which `dune build` fails with errors, in order to get the side effect of updating the .`opam` file, seems incorrect.

Is there either a dune subcommand that just updates the opam file with the dependencies in dune-project, or a dune subcommand that will update the opam file and also update the installed dependencies according to the updated opam file, as part of the build step?

Or is the above sequence of events the intended flow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The intended flow is:

- `opam install newdependency1 newdependency2 ...`
- edit `dune-project`
- `dune build`

Comment: But HOW do you edit dune project?

Comment: If you had `(depends dep1)` and want to add `dep2` and `dep3` you must change it to: `(depends dep1 dep2 dep3)`.
`

Comment: To me this is an acceptable answer to the question, because my question was really two questions: 1) if it's possible, how can I use the flow I described, and 2) is this the intended flow. This answer says that (2) what I described is not the intended flow. I assume, then,, that there is no way to do what I described.